# Cron task to run every hour between 10PM and 1AM

Tags: cron

I need a cron task to run once per hour between the hours of 10PM and 1AM.  Am I correct in assuming this is the formating for this task?

```
0 22-1/1 ? * *
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't assume it, I would test it. But, I'll take a stab and say that your cron might not work.

I would use:
0 0,1,22,23 * * *

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
0 22-23,0-1 * * * /home/scripts/my_job.sh
```

The asterisks (*) represent the time parameters for when the script should be executed. In this case, there are five asterisks, which correspond to the following time parameters:

- Minute (0-59)
- Hour (0-23)
- Day of the month (1-31)
- Month (1-12)
- Day of the week (0-6, where 0 represents Sunday)

Since all five asterisks are present, this means that the script will be executed at every minute, every hour, every day of the month, every month, and every day of the week.